# Java drawString limitation?

Tags: java, string

I want to draw a string with specific dimension/bounds.

I know how to draw strings in general and I know how to measure strings, which is an often asked question. I am also aware of different dpi-handling of Java on various operation systems and I know that Java resizes strings depending on the dimensions of the Graphics2D-object you draw on.

I would like to do something like:

```
graphics2d.drawString("Hello World", width, height);
```

(of course the above example would render the text at position width and height).

Is there an efficient way to do what i want?

I also have found a **very inefficient** solution to my problem:

1. create an Image of the size of the target screen/window
2. measure the text in this images graphics object
3. render text
4. create a sub-image of the text-area

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You may just set an appropriate clipping region to the graphics context (`setClip` methods).

Comment: Do you want to center a String in a Rectangle, or do you want to draw the String with the maximum font size, and have it fit within a Rectangle?  Your drawString method needs an origin as well as dimension.

Comment: Unless you are using a monospaced font, each glyph you are using can have a different width, which means you need to add the size of every glyph to know the width of one line, which is almost as computationally expensive as rendering the string itself into an offscreen buffer. BTW if you're using a vector-based font, then you might actually need to render a glyph it in order to know its size (not sure, though)

Comment: Darn, you're quick! ;-) 
Giulio: good point! I will do more performance testing on several systems,
Gilbert: this would work for me as well: drawing the string at big size, then scaling it (without considering aspect ratio!) to fit a rectangle of a specified size. I wonder how computationally expensive a good quality scaling might be though...

Comment: Indeed, since your final purpose is rendering the string, you might actually pre-render it to an off-screen buffer, and then just copy the offscreen buffer to the final buffer, so you don't even need to render the string twice. But this really sounds like premature optimization. I think the real question here is: have you really tried the **very inefficient** solutions you already found and determined they are **too inefficient** for your scope?

Comment: markbernard: it's just about the dimension, I have no problems positioning it.
Giulio: I tried it in C#/XNA and concluded it would be about as inefficient in Java. this operation would happen about 6'000 times per second and should not use more than 10% of the overall applications performance - i might need to rethink the whole architecture though so it mustn't happen as often - maybe an event handling system...

Comment: First thing: doing the double-render thing should be fairly easy. Just try it. Second: Java renders differently from XNA, so maybe it's worth giving it a try. Of course, the first thing to do would be to cache string sizes, and only update them when the string changes.

Comment: I will. thank you for your various inputs. I'll post my result as soon as I get to it. Best
P.S: I already cached the string sizes at various predefined "sizes" (enums)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the kind help of the community, I was able to write this method. I added some comments to make it clear(er) without posting the whole class. I someone is interested, I can post the whole class.

```
/**
 * Renders a string to a translucent image and returns it
 * @param string the text, like "Hello World"
 * @param size an enum, like SMALL, MIDDLE, LARGE
 * @param graphics the graphics of the scene, used for measuring the string-dimension
 * @return
 */
public BufferedImage renderTextToImage(String string, Size size, Color color, Graphics graphics) {
    Vector2 imageDimension = this.getFontDimensionPixels(string, size, graphics); // helper which measures string using fontmetrics
    BufferedImage returnImage = new BufferedImage(
            Max.maxInt((int)imageDimension.getX(), 1), // Max.maxInt() is a little helper to get the bigger out of two values
            Max.maxInt((int)imageDimension.getY(), 1),
            Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);
    Graphics2D returnGraphics = returnImage.createGraphics();
    returnGraphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    returnGraphics.setFont(this.getFont(size));
    returnGraphics.setColor(color);
    returnGraphics.drawString(string, 0, returnImage.getHeight() * 0.8f);
    returnGraphics.dispose();
    return returnImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java `JLabel`s determine their preferred size by calling `ui.getPreferredSize(this)`.
Usually, the ui for a label is BasicLabelUI, which internally uses `java.awt.FontMetrics` to compute the width required to draw a string.

Since the interface of `FontMetrics` is quite easy, you should probably use that, rather than trying to double-render the string, after all.

Comment: Since I want to reuse the text (as an Image) anyway, your original idea was actually very suitable. I'm almost done with the code and will post it asap in case someone else had a similar problem. Can I mark a comment as answer?